# Stored Procedure Batch Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a bunch of replaces on many rows in a table. What I'm doing isn't particularly difficult but I've been told to think about larger transactions or updates that I will be performing in the future that may take a long time.

So I need to think about interrupting the Update/Transaction to allow other queries etc to have a chance to run.

So I want to use this fairly simple task to ask how I might go about this.

Doing it as Batch statements has been suggested but I am a bit confused how to proceed.

```
UPDATE #tempresults
SET Col1 = REPLACE(Col1, 'A', '1');
UPDATE #tempresults
SET Col1 = REPLACE(Col1, 'B', '2');
UPDATE #tempresults
SET Col1 = REPLACE(Col1, 'C', '3');
UPDATE #tempresults
SET Col1 = REPLACE(Col1, 'D', '4');
```

Above is similar to what I'm trying to achieve but I need some pointers for what I'm looking for.

If this has been asked before please point me towards that question. If more information is needed from me please ask.

Comment: So your question is how to do this as fast as possible, or in different chunks?

Comment: >>>So I need to think about interrupting the Update/Transaction **to allow other queries** etc to have a chance to run<<< Other queries cannot run using THIS temporary table, it's only sisible to YOUR current session

Comment: Yes, you can do incremental update.

Comment: @sepupic Yes I understand I'm using a temp table in my given example. It was more of a general question for the future.

Comment: Also use GO after each statement. This will break each statement in multiple transactions instead of one transaction

Comment: What is the purpose of the first `UPDATE` since the value will be replaced by Col15 in the second update? It seems you could improve performance with a single `UPDATE` and nested `REPLACE` functions, and perform the operations in batches on top of that to improve concurrency and reduce transaction log needs.

Comment: @mvisser, each statement is an atomic transaction with or without `GO`. The default behavior is each statement is autocommitted.

Comment: @DanGuzman you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You might start by removing the unnecessary update (1st one) and then combining rest to a single update. ie:

```
UPDATE #tempresults
SET Col1 = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Col15, 
            'B', '2'),
            'C', '3'), 
            'D', '4');
```

You also need to be sure that your update really doesn't need a where clause? If this is not a one time job, you might instead think of defining a computed column that would this automatically for you.